# How to get value from array outside of loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How can I get the value of `oneHundredColorLevel` from the array and render it outside the container of the other colors? Each set of colors should be the boxes for each color, with a separate box for the `100` level color.

Link to [codepen](https://codepen.io/mattography/pen/QWgJPmP?editors=1010)

```
const colorPalette = {
Dark10: "#FEF9E8",
Dark20: "#FDF4DE",
Dark30: "#FCEFCC",
Dark40: "#F7E0A2",
Dark50: "#F0CC72",
Dark60: "#D5B363",
Dark70: "#C7A55E",
Dark80: "#B39553",
Dark90: "#9D8240",
Dark100: "#89723E",
Dark110: "#7C6737",
Dark120: "#715E32",
Dark130: "#66552E",
Dark140: "#5B4A28"
};

const ColorSwatches = ({ colors, shade }) => {
let filtered = Object.fromEntries(
    Object.entries(colors).filter(([key, value]) => key.includes(shade))
);
let onehundredcolor = [];
return (
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="bigNumber">
            <h1>{onehundredcolor}</h1><----SHOULD BE NAME ONLY
            <p>{onehundredcolor}</p><----SHOULD BE HEX VALUE ONLY
        </div>
        {Object.entries(filtered).map((color, i) => {
            if (i === 9) {
                onehundredcolor.push(color);
                console.log(onehundredcolor)
            }else if(i !== 9) {
            return (
                <div key={i} style={{ backgroundColor: `${color[1]}` }}>
                    <h2>{color[0]}</h2>
                    <p>HEX {color[1]}</p>
                </div>
            );
            }
        })
    </div>
);
};
```

Comment: What is `oneHundredColorLevel`? It doesn't appear in your code.

Comment: BTW an array would seem to be much easier to use here than an object whose properties are the various shade/color pairs. For example: `[ {shade: 'dark', color: '#FEF9E8'}, ... ]`. Then you can filter/map as you see fit. And you can easily access the 10th dark color via `colorList.filter(c => c.shade === 'dark')[9]`.

Comment: @jarmod - I refactored my code and got it working (don't know why I had my colors as an object...). If you can post your comment as an answer, I'll mark it correct. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that an array would be a more flexible container here than an object whose properties are the various shade/color pairs. For example:

```
const colors = [
    {shade: 'dark', color: '#FEF9E8'},
    {shade: 'dark', color: '#FDF4DE'},
    ...
    {shade: 'light', color: '#111111'},
    {shade: 'light', color: '#111122'},
    ...
];
```

Then you can filter/map as you see fit, for example:

```
const darkColors = colors.filter(c => c.shade === 'dark');
const lightColors = colors.filter(c => c.shade === 'light');
```

And you can easily access the 10th dark color via:

```
darkColors[9]
```